# C++ memory leaks by static variable

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, memory-leaks, static

Visual Studio 2012 tells me that the following program has memory leaks. Is this correct and if so how can I avoid memory leaks when using (for example) static vectors?

```
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <vector>

struct A {
  static std::vector<int> a;
};
std::vector<int> A::a;

int main()
{
  _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's reporting a "leak" because you call it too early. If you remove the call to `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks` and run in Debug, do you get any leak report?

Comment: @RogerRowland Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't that call neccessary to produce the memory leak report?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are calling the function before the static variable's scope has finished. And so it is wrong for you to expect that the variable has been destroyed.

You need to wait until the scope is over before you call that function. Of course that is hard to do, but the runtime can help you, as described in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d41t22sb.aspx):

> The function can be called automatically at program termination by turning on the _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF bit field of the _crtDbgFlag flag using the _CrtSetDbgFlag function.